# Django model form with selected rows

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms

I have a django model roughly as  shown below:

```
class Event(db.Model):
   creator = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required= True)
   title = db.TextProperty(required = True)
   description = db.TextProperty(required = True)

class Ticket(db.Model):
   user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required = True)
   event = db.ReferenceProperty(Event, required = True)
   total_seats = db.IntegerProperty(required = True,default=0)
   available_seats = db.IntegerProperty(required = True,default=0)
```

Now I want to create a form from this model which should contain the events which are own by the logged in users only. Currently it shows a drop down with all the events in it.

Is it possible with django forms? I am working on google app engine.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd go about it if this were a pure Django application (rather than app engine). You may perhaps find it useful.

The key is to override the `__init__()` method of your `ModelForm` class to supply the currently logged in user instance.

```
# forms.py
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, current_user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['event'].queryset = Event.objects.filter(creator = 
             current_user)
```

You can then supply the user instance while creating an instance of the form.

```
ticket_form = TicketForm(request.user)
```

Comment: anand, would you mind posting what those "small changes" were that made it work? Thanks!

Comment: Just the change in the query to fetch the result. like: Event.all().filter('creator =',current_user) will work with google app engine. slight difference in syntax in pure django and app engine.